# Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \sin \frac{1}{x} = 1$ using $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} =1$

Tags: limits

> Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \sin \frac{1}{x} = 1$ using $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} =1$

Using Sandwich theorem, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin \frac{1}{x} = \infty$

I cant seem to simplify it to the form of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} =1$, can i get a hint

Comment: No, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin\frac 1x$ is not $\infty.$ How did you deduce this with the Sandwich theorem?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews    I used the sandwich thereom to simplify the function

Comment: Tell us how you "simplify the function." Because it isn't correct, and we can't show what you did wrong if you don't tell us what you did.

Comment: In particular, $|\sin\theta|\leq 1,$ there is no way to have $\sin\frac 1x>1.$

Comment: @thomasandrews yes, I made a mistake, the sandwich theorem does not proof that correctly,

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim\limits_{u \to 0^+} \dfrac{\sin u}{u} = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=1/x$, then

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} x \sin(1/x)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t}=1.$$

Comment: It should be the limit as $t\to 0^+$; while the two sided limit also equals $1$, it does not follow from the substitution.